# Как разрешить регистрацию на один и тот же email несколько Аккаунтов wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, html

Доброго времени друзья. Я хочу чтобы на моем сайте пользователь мог создавать хоть сто аккаунтов на один и тот же email адрес) не спрашивайте зачем эта глупость) просто подскажите как это сделать? какой файл отредактировать чтобы не выходило вот такое сообщение : Извините, этот адрес e-mail уже используется!

Comment: не знаю как там в вордпресс, но дело в том, что на email высылается код активации поэтом он должен быть уникальным, если же код активации не высылается, тогда зачем вообще нужно поле email

Comment: @Валентин Жуков

> поэтом он должен быть уникальным

C чего бы?

> если же код активации не высылается, тогда зачем вообще нужно поле email

действительно!

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего в базе данных у поля email убрать атрибут первичный ключ, ну и в register убрать проверку email на уникальность, я с wordpress не работал, но это стандартная процедура!